# Annotate: Retornando o produto mais barato e o nome do fornecedor (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Dada a tabela a seguir

```
product;company;price 
AAAAA;forn1;395.69 
BBBBB;forn1;939.45 
CCCCC;forn1;480.33 
DDDDD;forn1;590.59 
EEEEE;forn1;847.69 
AAAAA;forn2;227.31 
BBBBB;forn2;375.90 
CCCCC;forn2;602.18 
DDDDD;forn2;615.02 
EEEEE;forn2;845.20 
AAAAA;forn3;120.00 
BBBBB;forn3;379.30 
CCCCC;forn3;227.98 
DDDDD;forn3;522.33 
EEEEE;forn3;193.51 
AAAAA;forn4;869.01 
BBBBB;forn4;287.48 
CCCCC;forn4;405.49 
DDDDD;forn4;477.97 
EEEEE;forn4;971.85
```

como retornar o menor preço de cada produto e retornar o nome do fornecedor?

Já tentei:

```
from django.db.models import Min

q=Quotation.objects.values('product').annotate(m=Min('price'))
for i in q: print(i)
```

E ele retorna

```
{'product': 'AAAAA', 'm': Decimal('120.00')}
{'product': 'BBBBB', 'm': Decimal('287.48')}
{'product': 'CCCCC', 'm': Decimal('227.98')}
{'product': 'DDDDD', 'm': Decimal('477.97')}
{'product': 'EEEEE', 'm': Decimal('193.51')}
```

Mas ele nao retorna o fornecedor. Dai quando eu tento

```
q=Quotation.objects.values('product').annotate(m=Min('price')).values_list('product','company','m')
for i in q: print(i)
```

Ele retorna

```
('AAAAA', 'forn1', Decimal('395.69'))
('AAAAA', 'forn2', Decimal('227.31'))
('AAAAA', 'forn3', Decimal('120.00'))
('AAAAA', 'forn4', Decimal('869.01'))
('BBBBB', 'forn1', Decimal('939.45'))
('BBBBB', 'forn2', Decimal('375.90'))
('BBBBB', 'forn3', Decimal('379.30'))
('BBBBB', 'forn4', Decimal('287.48'))
('CCCCC', 'forn1', Decimal('480.33'))
('CCCCC', 'forn2', Decimal('602.18'))
('CCCCC', 'forn3', Decimal('227.98'))
('CCCCC', 'forn4', Decimal('405.49'))
('DDDDD', 'forn1', Decimal('590.59'))
('DDDDD', 'forn2', Decimal('615.02'))
('DDDDD', 'forn3', Decimal('522.33'))
('DDDDD', 'forn4', Decimal('477.97'))
('EEEEE', 'forn1', Decimal('847.69'))
('EEEEE', 'forn2', Decimal('845.20'))
('EEEEE', 'forn3', Decimal('193.51'))
('EEEEE', 'forn4', Decimal('971.85'))
```

E nao eh o que eu quero, eu preciso de

```
{'product': 'AAAAA', 'company': 'forn2' 'm': Decimal('120.00')}
{'product': 'BBBBB', 'company': 'forn1' 'm': Decimal('287.48')}
{'product': 'CCCCC', 'company': 'forn1' 'm': Decimal('227.98')}
{'product': 'DDDDD', 'company': 'forn3' 'm': Decimal('477.97')}
{'product': 'EEEEE', 'company': 'forn4' 'm': Decimal('193.51')}
```

Ou seja, como eu faco para retornar o produto mais barato e o nome do fornecedor?

Comment: Já tentou adicionar 'company' em `values()`? `q=Quotation.objects.values('product', 'company'`).annotate(m=Min('price'))`

Comment: Sim, mas dai ele agrupa por product e por company. E nao eh isso que eu quero.

Comment: [Solução para Django 1.11 ou superior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/224234/215)

Answer (score 3):

([TL;DR](https://anaconda.org/sidon/min_prod/notebook))
 
Se a tabela não tiver 'zilhões' de registros, voce pode carregar a tabela inteira para a memória e filtrar com o pandas, veja o exemplo abaixo.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

# Simulando a tabela
s = '''
product,company,price
AAAAA,forn1,395.69
BBBBB,forn1,939.45
CCCCC,forn1,480.33
DDDDD,forn1,590.59
EEEEE,forn1,847.69
AAAAA,forn2,227.31
BBBBB,forn2,375.90
CCCCC,forn2,602.18
DDDDD,forn2,615.02
EEEEE,forn2,845.20
AAAAA,forn3,120.00
BBBBB,forn3,379.30
CCCCC,forn3,227.98
DDDDD,forn3,522.33
EEEEE,forn3,193.51
AAAAA,forn4,869.01
BBBBB,forn4,287.48
CCCCC,forn4,405.49
DDDDD,forn4,477.97
EEEEE,forn4,971.85
'''
# Criando o pandas dataframe (Carregando a tabela)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), usecols=['product','company','price'])

# Agrupando os minimos
df.loc[df.groupby(['product'])['price'].idxmin()]
```

**Output:**

```
    product company price
10  AAAAA   forn3   120.00
16  BBBBB   forn4   287.48
12  CCCCC   forn3   227.98
18  DDDDD   forn4   477.97
14  EEEEE   forn3   193.51
```

[Veja rodando em um jupyter notebook.](https://anaconda.org/sidon/min_prod/notebook)

Answer (score 2):

Resolvido com uma solucao diferente (mas ainda aceito uma solucao melhor e menor).

No final ficou assim

```
from core.models import Quotation
from django.db.models import Min

q=Quotation.objects.values('product').annotate(m=Min('price'))
for i in q: print(i)

{'product': 'AAAAA', 'm': Decimal('120.00')}
{'product': 'BBBBB', 'm': Decimal('287.48')}
{'product': 'CCCCC', 'm': Decimal('227.98')}
{'product': 'DDDDD', 'm': Decimal('477.97')}
{'product': 'EEEEE', 'm': Decimal('193.51')}
```

Retorna os produtos mais baratos, mas nao retorna o fornecedor.

```
from django.db import connection
len(connection.queries)
1
```

**Solucao:**

```
q=Quotation.objects.values_list('product').annotate(m=Min('price'))
c=[]
for i in q: c.append(Quotation.objects.get(product=i[0],price=i[1]))

for co in c: co.product, co.company, co.price

('AAAAA', 'forn3', Decimal('120.00'))
('BBBBB', 'forn4', Decimal('287.48'))
('CCCCC', 'forn3', Decimal('227.98'))
('DDDDD', 'forn4', Decimal('477.97'))
('EEEEE', 'forn3', Decimal('193.51'))
```

Retorna uma lista com o produto, o fornecedor e o menor preco. **OK**, era tudo que eu queria, mas...

**Problema**: baixa performance.

```
from django.db import connection
len(connection.queries)
6
```

**Pergunta:** como melhorar isso?

Comment: [Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/224437/7412) não serve?

Comment: @Sidon É uma alternativa interessante, mas [essa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/224234/215) dá uma solução usando Django puro. De todo modo, obrigado pela sugestão.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi direito a [parte do manual referente a subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#s-subquery-expressions), você poderia implementar a consulta desta forma:

```
outros_precos_menores = Quotation.objects.filter(
    product=OuterRef('product'),
    price__lt=OuterRef('price'),
)

precos_menores = Quotation.objects.annotate(nao_tem_menor=~Exists(outros_precos_menores)).filter(nao_tem_menor=True)

for p in precos_menores:
    print(p)
```

Uma alternativa seria usar SQL diretamente.
Dê uma olhada na documentação do Django em [Performing raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/)

SQL usando tabela derivada:

```
select
    qt.product,
    qt.company,
    qt.price

from (
    select qt2.product, Min(qt2.price) as min_price
    from Quotation qt2
    group by qt2.product
) preco

inner join Quotation qt on  qt.product = preco.product
                        and qt.price   = preco.min_price
```

SQL usando subselect:

```
select
    qt.product,
    qt.company,
    qt.price

from Quotation qt
where qt.price = (  
    select Min(qt2.price)
    from Quotation qt2
    where qt2.product = qt.product
)
```

Você poderia tentar algo como:

```
sql = """
select
    qt.product,
    qt.company,
    qt.price

from Quotation qt
where qt.price = (  
    select Min(qt2.price)
    from Quotation qt2
    where qt2.product = qt.product
)
"""

for p in Quotation.objects.raw(sql):
    print(p)
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado! P.S. Tem um errinho no seu código, o campo `post` na verdade deveria ser `product`. Vou sugerir uma edição consertando isso e movendo a solução sem raw SQL pro topo, ok?

Comment: Ah, também vale a pena mencionar que essa solução só está disponível a partir do Django 1.11